# Why carry out the experiments in the Gyeongseong hospital?

Tags: gyeongseong-creature

In the first episode of *Gyeongseong Creature*, we see that the experiments to create Najin were initially carried out exactly where one might expect top-secret and highly dangerous weapons development to be conducted—a dedicated military installation in a remote, snowy wilderness, possibly in Manchuria, where it would be easy to carry out experiments without anyone asking questions, verify every coming and going, and to destroy evidence when it became necessary.

However, they then changed location to Gyeongseong—that is, Seoul—a major metropolis with a population of about a million. Moreover, the location chosen for the experiments was an *operational* hospital, that was used for medical care for out-of-the-loop Japanese administrators and even a few well-connected and collaborative Koreans, *while* the experiments were being conducted just a few floors below! Logically enough,  this leads to a large number of security and secrecy issues over the course of the first season.

Presumably, the Japanese armed forces had good reason to abandon their previous installation (perhaps Allied advancement). But why did the people conducting the experiments decide to change to this particular fairly conspicuous and difficult-to-secure location?

Answer (score 1):

Season 1 takes place in 1945 after the Bombing of Tokyo (March, 9), probably at the very beginning of April since it is the cherry blossom season (for comparison, cherry blossom started [on April,2 last year](https://english.visitkorea.or.kr/svc/contents/infoHtmlView.do?vcontsId=134816)). They may have left Manchuria because it was hard to defend at the time.

Also, the official purpose of the experiments was to improve Japanese knowledge of the human body. It seems that Lieutenant Colonel Kato discovered the way to create the creature and kept it secret at first: Ichiro, the director of the hospital didn't know about the creature, but hoped to use it as a weapon to save Japan after finding out.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what the story is about, but "Japanese forces" and "Allied advancement" lead me to believe it's during WWII and that leads to a simple conclusion:

Moving experiments to a civilian hospital provides protection from bombing as a military target, while leaving it at a remote location leaves it vulnerable to bombing/attack if/when the location and its purposes are discovered.

Comment: Does it really though? As the other answer pointed out, this was *after* things like the bombing of Tokyo and Dresden. Or the Blitz, for that matter. No one would have hesitate to bomb the hospital.

Comment: The other answer was posted 7 days after mine, and, as I noted, I haven't seen the show, just making some general assumptions.